# What is the purpose of the replace parameter for the sample function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am asking about this feature:

```
df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1)
```

available as an option upon sampling a DataFrame.

On the pandas [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), it says it is to:

> Sample with or without replacement.

What does this mean and what are some uses for this?

Comment: If you google "Sampling with and without replacement", you'll get many explanations from statistics. For example: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm. It's the same idea in pandas. With replacement means you can get the same row repeated in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indicates if an input row could appear more than once in the output.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)})

# Here, row 5 is duplicated
print (df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1))

5  5
8  8
9  9
5  5
0  0

# Here, all values are unique
print (df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=False, random_state=1))
   a
2  2
9  9
6  6
4  4
0  0
```

You can check this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40689152):

> It controls whether the sample is returned to the sample pool. If you want only unique samples then this should be false.

Comment: That's not necessarily true, if the dataframe itself contains duplicate rows, you could still get duplicates without replacement.