# Python Bootstrap Sample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function `create_bootstrap_sample` (using `X_train` as input) that accepts Pandas DataFrame as a parameter and returns a bootstrap sample (also as a Pandas DataFrame).

```
def create_bootstrap_sample(df):
    pass
```

I wanted help with completing the code.

Comment: This can be used for printing output                                                                               
print('-'*60)
print('Number of rows should be the same:')
print('Number of rows in X_train:  ', X_train.shape[0])
print('Number of rows in bootstrap:', create_bootstrap_sample(X_train).shape[0])
print('-'*60)
print('Row labels of bootstrap should have repeated values:')
print('Contains repeat row labels:', bool(~create_bootstrap_sample(X_train).index.is_unique))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the replace parameter for the sample function in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095898/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-replace-parameter-for-the-sample-function-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the function that you need:

```
pandas.DataFrame.sample
```

*Return a random sample of items from an axis of object.*

It even contains this parameter:

```
replace: bool, default False
```

*Allow or disallow sampling of the same row more than once.*